# Convert to and from signed octal

Tags: code-golf, math, number, base-conversion

Write some code to do the following:

1. Take as its input a signed integer in either signed decimal or signed octal
   (explained below)
2. If the number is decimal convert it to octal. If it's octal, convert it to decimal
3. Output the number!

Instead of starting with a `0`, negative octal numbers will start with a `Z` (capital zed).
In the same way that -1 is commonly encoded in binary as all `1`s, in signed octal it is encoded as all `7`s. -2 is all `7`s except for the final digit which is `6`, and so on.

Your code must accept leading `0`s, or `7`s (after the initial `Z` in octal) but must not output leading `0`s for decimal or non-negative octal, with the exception of a single `0` to indicate octal format, and must not output leading `7`s in the case of negative octal. `0` is valid as an entire number in both decimal and octal and is the only number to have an identical representation in both. Decimal numbers must not have any leading zeros and must be interpreted as octal if they do (i.e. `08` should be interpreted as neither decimal nor octal). Note that `0`s immediately after the `Z` are significant and must not be truncated. `Z` is shorthand for an infinite number of `7`s. You may assume that the input will always be valid and not check for it in your code.

```
 Input : Output  
-1 : Z  
-10: Z66
-5: Z3
10: 012
-30000: Z05320
-10000: Z54360
0  : 0
01234: 668
Z1234: -3428
Z77777: -1
00777: 511
Z6000: -1024
```

A table of the first few positive and negative signed octal numbers:

```
+ve -ve
  0   0
 01  Z
 02  Z6
 03  Z5
 04  Z4
 05  Z3
 06  Z2
 07  Z1
010  Z0
011 Z67
012 Z66
```

Make it small!

Comment: Doesn't octal zero have to be `00`?

Comment: Could you remove the second part of the challenge (overflow) as it is not very related?

Comment: 1. "*Decimal numbers must not have any leading digits and must be interpreted as octal if they do.*" What does this mean? It seems to contradict itself. 2. How many bits are required to represent a negative number? 3. It took me some careful thinking to realise that `Z` is shorthand for an infinite string of `..777`. But then the natural representation for `-1` seems to be `Z` rather than `Z7`. Can answers give either in output? Can they choose to accept only one in input?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Replace "digits" with "zeroes", I think.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I did mean "digits" but I've changed it to "0"s and "7"s.

Comment: The contradiction I see is that a number is either decimal or octal. I think the confusion could be avoided by explicitly stating that if it starts with 0 or Z it's octal: otherwise it's decimal; and 0 is a special case for which the output is 0.